# Priority and association of terms in an expression evaluator with exponentiation operator

Tags: evaluator

I am developing an expression evaluator. Which association is considered to be correct for an expression containing more than one exponentiation operator? For example, for the expression `"10-2^2^0.5"`: `"10-(2^2) ^0.5"= 8` or `"10-2^ (2^0.5)" = 7.33485585731`?

Answer (score 0):

The result differs across languages and (possible) interpreters. However, most of them uses right-associative rule.
In Lua `print(10-2^2^0.5)` returns 7.3348 and in Visual Basic, `Console.WriteLine(10-2^2^0.5)` returns 8.
The fact that different systems uses different rules suggest me that there is no defined rule for that.